# Stripe apis return empty data when connected over Extension OAuth

Tags: stripe-payments

I have implemented an app that uses Stripe Oauth implementation, after following the instructions in the [building extensions](https://stripe.com/docs/building-extensions#use-api)

Authentication is done perfectly. I'm able to retrieve access token and other details.

```
{
  "access_token":"sk_test_51KHr6dAuxxxx",
  "refresh_token":"rt_KxmgQFvxxxx",
  "expires_in":1642171943,
  "livemode":false,
  "stripe_publishable_key":"pk_test_51KHr6dxxx",
  "stripe_user_id":"acct_1KHrxxxx"
}
```

Now the problem comes when trying to get resources from Stripe. If an API call is made to `https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers`, an empty data is returned.

```
{
    "object": "list",
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/customers"
}
```

At the same time, if customer "key (secret test mode API key.)" is used, that endpoint return 4 customers (all of them).

So clearly, the access token received after OAuth is missing something.

Also tried adding the `Stripe-Account` key and customer account id in the headers, and received the following error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "platform_account_required",
        "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/platform-account-required",
        "message": "Only Stripe Connect platforms can work with other accounts. If you specified a client_id parameter, make sure it's correct. If you need to setup a Stripe Connect platform, you can do so at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/applications/settings.",
        "type": "invalid_request_error"
    }
}
```

I suspect something might be wrong with the app itself, but not sure :D

**EDIT**

Adding a few tried items using `composer require stripe/stripe-php`

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_51KHxxx");
return \Stripe\Customer::all()
```

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_51Kxxx');
return $stripe->customers->all(['limit' => 30]);
```

Comment: can you share the code which you've tried retrieving the customer?

Comment: @alex tried the exact steps mentioned in https://stripe.com/docs/building-extensions. Tried with Stripe PHP library and via postman also

Comment: @alex tried creating a client as well according to https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=php

Comment: It's not going to be possible to help you without additional details such as the exact code snippets which you've tried. I'll suggest reaching out to Stripe Support. They may be able retrieve the request that is returning that specific error from your Stripe account to troubleshoot.

Comment: @alex my bad. Updated a few things tried.

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when you try to make a request from an account that is not a platform account i.e. it has no Connected accounts.

Looking at your code snippets, I'm guessing that you're making the request with the connected account's secret key since the first few characters are the same.

When making Connect requests, you should be using the API key that belongs to the platform account and then provide the optional stripe_account parameter [0].

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY");
$customers = \Stripe\Customer::all([],["stripe_account" => "CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID"]);
```

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication